# Show list of transactions depending on its status

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this PagerAdapter where I need to filter a list of CouponTransactions depending on its status. I used to have only two status: PENDING and EXPIRED. But now I need to add one more USED.
Now I am trying to show all transactions with status PENDING on the POSITION_PENDING and the rest (EXPIRED and USED) in the other tab. How can I achieve this? Right now my createListView method only accepts one status, so I don't really know how to show the transactions for both EXPIRED and USED on the second tab.

```
class WalletTransactionsPagerAdapter(
  private val context: Context,
  private val transactions: List<CouponTransaction>
) : PagerAdapter() {

  companion object {
    private const val NUM_PAGES = 2
    private const val POSITION_PENDING = 0
    private const val POSITION_EXPIRED = 1
  }

  override fun getCount(): Int = NUM_PAGES

  override fun instantiateItem(
    container: ViewGroup,
    position: Int
  ): Any = when (position) {
    POSITION_EXPIRED -> createListView(context, EXPIRED, transactions)
    else -> createListView(context, PENDING, transactions)
  }.also { safeView ->
    container.addView(safeView, 0)
  }

  private fun createListView(
    context: Context,
    status: CouponTransactionStatus,
    transactions: List<CouponTransaction>
  ): RecyclerView = RecyclerView(context).apply {
    layoutManager = VerticalLayoutManager(context)
    setHasFixedSize(true)
    adapter = WalletTransactionAdapter(transactions.filter { it.status == status })
  }

...
}
```

```
  enum class CouponTransactionStatus(val value: String) {
    @SerializedName("unknown")
    UNKNOWN("unknown"),

    @SerializedName("active")
    PENDING("active"),

    @SerializedName("used")
    USED("used"),

    @SerializedName("expired")
    EXPIRED("expired");

    companion object {
      val DEFAULT: CouponTransactionStatus = UNKNOWN
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the filtered list to the `createListView` method instead of performing the filter operation in the method. Like so:

```kotlin
class WalletTransactionsPagerAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val transactions: List<CouponTransaction>
) : PagerAdapter() {

    companion object {
        private const val NUM_PAGES = 2
        private const val POSITION_PENDING = 0
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int = NUM_PAGES

    override fun instantiateItem(
        container: ViewGroup,
        position: Int
    ): Any = when (position) {
        POSITION_PENDING -> {
            val pendingTransactions = transactions.filter { it.status == PENDING }
            createListView(context, pendingTransactions)
        }
        else -> {
            val otherTransactions = transactions.filterNot { it.status == PENDING }
            createListView(context, otherTransactions)
        }
    }.also { safeView ->
        container.addView(safeView, 0)
    }

    private fun createListView(
        context: Context,
        transactions: List<CouponTransaction>
    ): RecyclerView = RecyclerView(context).apply {
        layoutManager = VerticalLayoutManager(context)
        setHasFixedSize(true)
        adapter = WalletTransactionAdapter(transactions)
    }

    ...
}
```